Dividing a polyhedron into two similar copies
The paper Dividing a polygon into two similar polygons proves that there are only three families of polygons that are irrep-2-tiles (can be subdivided into similar copies of the original).

Right angled triangles
$1:\sqrt{2}$ parallelograms
The Golden Bee

I wish to find examples of polyhedra that are irrep-2-tiles. The only example I have been able to find is:

The $1:2^\frac{1}{3}:2^\frac{2}{3}$ parallelopipeds.

Are there further examples?
This question originates  on MathStackExchange.

Diagram of the irregular solution in two dimensions from the linked paper:


I am not sure if this question is difficult or just really, really niche. I've added a bounty which I'll award for any information relevant to the question.

Definitely not tetrahedra, see this paper.  The proof generalizes to other families of polytopes, actually.  For example, by Sydler's theorem these cannot be polytopes with nonzero Dehn invariant ($\Leftrightarrow$ not scissor congruent to a cube), see Theorem 16.2 in my book.   None of this contradicts some 3-dim analogue of "The Golden Bee", of course.

Thank you! I'll upvote this answer as soon as I get back the reputation needed to do so. Your book looks like a wonderful resource.
I was aware that no tetrahedra is an $n$-reptile for $n\le 7$, but using this together with Dehn invariant is neat.
